# php/perl or other web script capable of automatic authentication to a SmartCard Enabled Website

Tags: php, perl, x509, smartcard

I have a php script that goes to a rss feed url and pulls down the xml, processes it and then loads the data I need into a database.  The script has been working flawlessly, until the site owners secured it using smartcard authentication(Military CAC).

I've been trying to figure out a way to take my x.509 cert from my smartcard and present it via php or any other scripting language to the webserver hosting the rss.  I can't see to figure this out.

Concept of operations:
1. Request rss url
2. rss url requests authentication
3. present cert + pin(I'll store the pin securely for the script to use, I know how to do this)
4. rss url authenticates my cert and posts the data.

Thanks!
-Dan

Comment: In Perl/CPAN, see: Crypt::X509, Authen::Credential::x509, Crypt::NSS::Certificate, and Web::ID::Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP would this work (using [phpseclib, a pure-PHP X.509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html))?:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...');
echo $x509->validateSignature() ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
?>
```

Other things you could validate against are listed below:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#validate

Comment: I don't think this would work.  I'm not trying to validate my signature.  I'm trying to access a web server I have no control over and present my cert for validation, then pull data from it.

Comment: So what specifically do you need help with?  You can get the cert from the smart card, it sounds like.  Do you need help with uploading it to the web server or extracting data from the cert (or webserver) or something?

Comment: Essentially I need to read my cert, open an ssl session to a website, that session needs to use my cert to create the ssl tunnel and validates that my cert is from a trusted CA, after that I should be able to pull the html or xml down from the site.